# What are the benefits in making the built-in "OrderedEnumerable" class internal?

Tags: c#, class

I noticed there is a concrete implementation of the `IOrderedEnumerable` interface and that is the `OrderedEnumerable.cs` class. However I also noticed it's internal and you can't use it in your code.

What are the benefits to this, as I wonder what could be drawbacks in making it public and why would the runtime need this class, at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The runtime needs this class because the `OrderBy()` and `OrderByDescending()` methods have to return something that behaves the way you'd expect an `IOrderedEnumerable` to behave.

The benefits of making it `internal` are the same as the benefits for all [Information Hiding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding)/Encapsulation: the .NET team is free to change that class without worrying that they'll break other people's code.

For example, the OrderedEnumerable constructor [takes more arguments now](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v8.0.1/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/OrderedEnumerable.cs#L113) than [it used to](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L2573). Since the class is `internal`, they only had to change their own code to accommodate that change.

If it were `public`, you or I might have been tempted to write code that creates a `new OrderedEnumerable<TKey, TValue>(...)`. Then when we upgraded to the next framework version, it would have broken our code because that constructor signature doesn't exist anymore.

Teams that write libraries try to be very careful to only expose "interfaces" (not just C# `interface`s, but also method signatures, types, etc.) that they're willing to maintain backwards-compatibility for indefinitely. They make everything internal or private by default, and only make things `public` after careful consideration.

Another benefit is that it keeps their public-facing surface clean and devoted to the kinds of things they expect people to do with their library. If every class and method in their library were exposed, our Intellisense menus would be filled with options that we'd probably never actually want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Any part of the public surface of a library becomes something that must be maintained in future. For any library published to such a wide audience, particular care must be taken when making any type public.

Linq in particular is designed to be as efficient as possible at runtime. Many of the `Enumerable` extension methods are defined to return an interface, but  at runtime they will examine the provided argument and attempt to return an optimised implementation of each type.

For example `Enumerable.OrderBy` [may return](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/cc5f1df48e5e39a6fa5ab94ca4664aac3cc36898/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/OrderBy.cs#L45) an instance of `OrderedImplicitlyStableEnumerable` instead of `OrderedEnumerable`.